# HTML - Prevent horizontal scrolling when zooming in on mobile

Tags: html, meta

When you zoom in an ordinary web page (without any `meta` tags) on desktop browsers, the page width will change to fit the screen. However when zooming in on mobile browsers, you will get a horizontal scrolling bar which is quite annoying. Can I achieve the same results on mobile browsers?

Example: http://motherfuckingwebsite.com/
Zoom in to 500% on desktop browsers: no horizontal scrollbar.
Zoom in a little bit on mobile browser: HORIZONTAL SCROLLBAR!!!!

Comment: I don't know about your html design structure but try to set overflow:hidden; to body.

Comment: What Parameters are in your `<head>` Area?

Comment: It doesn't matter. You can reproduce this on pretty much all webpages that allows zooming, including one that doesn't even have a `<head>`.

Comment: When I zoom in on SO I get a horizontal Scrolling Bar in my Desktop Browser

Comment: @j_s_stack Not until you reach the minimum width of this site. :/