# How to Make Webpage Adjust to Zooming In on Mobile

Tags: html, css

When on a desktop/laptop, if you zoom in on a website, the text (and entire page) adjusts to fit the screen. However, when you zoom in on mobile, you instead scroll horizontally, and no elements adjust for the new zoom.

Why is this? Is there any way to make mobile browsers mimic the behavior of desktop browsers so that the webpage adjusts to the zoom?

The relevant parts of my `<head>` tag:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

I'm also using Bootstrap CSS.

Regular zoom on mobile:

[Regular zoom on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeGU8.png)

Current behavior on mobile (page is cropped, horizontal scrolling enabled):

[Current behavior on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ddcg9.png)

Desired behavior on mobile (aka current behavior on desktop). Margins adjust to fit new screen width:

[Desired behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Bv6G.png)

---

Possible duplicate of [HTML - Prevent horizontal scrolling when zooming in on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27956032/html-prevent-horizontal-scrolling-when-zooming-in-on-mobile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is: probably don't do this, it's terribly inaccessible.

That said, if you want to do this, look into the two viewports described by [Viewport concepts - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Viewport_concepts). Basically, you need to modify your component boxes to render based on the size of the visual viewport, not the layout viewport:

> When the user pinch-zooms the page, pops open a dynamic keyboard, or when a previously hidden address bar becomes visible, the visual viewport shrinks but the layout viewport is unchanged.

-- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Viewport_concepts#:%7E:text=When%20the%20user%20pinch%2Dzooms%20the%20page%2C%20pops%20open%20a%20dynamic%20keyboard%2C%20or%20when%20a%20previously%20hidden%20address%20bar%20becomes%20visible%2C%20the%20visual%20viewport%20shrinks%20but%20the%20layout%20viewport%20is%20unchanged)

Answer (score -1):

To achieve that, in css of body tag, set `overflow` to `. Also [Refer](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)

```css
body{
font-size:100px;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<body>asdklajflksjfklaklsjklsfajklasjflkajfalshgkdhioqwefmahlashjfdhkjhaslkfhlakjhldhlkjhfsajlkhalksj</body>
```

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem: This prevents the user from seeing the overflow text, which is the opposite of my question. I would like the content width to automatically adjust to the zoomed-in width so it doesn't overflow and the user can always see it.